# Contentful do not retrieve all entries correctly / Needs to unpublish and publish again entries in order to get it

Tags: next.js, graphql, contentful, contentful-api

Im using nextjs app with contentful and grapqhl, In general im trying to get all my Entries for a specific content type but for some reason i dont get it full, some are missing and i need to publish and unpublish the entries in order to get them. but prob some miss doing this.

Im doing something like this

```
async function getApps(
        pageSkip = 0,
        itemLimit = 1000,
        entries: AppSitemapFragment[] = []
    ): Promise<AppSitemapFragment[]> {
        try {
            const { marketplaceAppCollection } = await client().request(AppsSitemapDocument, {
                limit: itemLimit,
                skip: pageSkip,
                where: { slug_exists: true }
            })

            if (!marketplaceAppCollection) return entries

            const { skip, limit, total, items } = marketplaceAppCollection

            entries.push(...items.filter(isNonNullable))

            if (total > limit * (skip + 1)) {
                return entries.concat(await getApps(skip + 1, limit))
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
        return entries
    }
```

In this case Client is my contentful client.

```
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'

type Args = {
    preview?: boolean
}

export const client = ({ preview }: Args = {}) => {
    return new GraphQLClient(
        `https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}/environments/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT}`,
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${
                    Boolean(preview)
                        ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_TOKEN
                        : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
                }`
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Do you have any Idea why this could happends?

Also this is my graphql

```
fragment AppSitemap on MarketplaceApp {
    sys {
        publishedAt
    }
    slug
    seoMetadata {
        noindex
        nofollow
    }
}

query AppsSitemap(
    $where: MarketplaceAppFilter = { slug_exists: true }
    $limit: Int = 1000
    $skip: Int = 0
    $locale: String
) {
    marketplaceAppCollection(where: $where, limit: $limit, skip: $skip, locale: $locale) {
        total
        skip
        limit
        items {
            ...AppSitemap
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are items loaded correctly when you use the graphql playground instead of in the web app?